# How to remove Hyper-v made Ubuntu machines .vhdx?

Tags: hyper-v

How to remove Hyper-v made Ubuntu machines?

Where is location of all of them?

What are default locations?

How to find removed machines, that had different locations of .vhdx files? How to find all hidden folders that dont show .vhdx files? Theres some folder that i cant access not to tamper with files, but also now i dont know where files are and takes last space!

Are theese all locations?

Why using Multipass theres only 1 or 2 GB file, and Ubuntu Multipass uses Hyper-v, but when in Hyper-v without Ubuntu Multipass i create myself, then it makes another file, Not Only Virtual Hard Disks but also Virtual Machines

[image]

Comment: @user535733 ubuntu Multipass uses Hyper-v. Also using basic Hyper-v is built in to choose Ubuntu. Also here is tag Hyper-v. So it makes them related to work on one or other.